# Android picture call back data is null

Tags: android

I am using camera code for Android after taking the picture the byte[] imageData parameter is null, I don't know why.

```
package com.pictures;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class CamaraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
        OnClickListener {
    static final int FOTO_MODE = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "CameraTest";
    Camera mCamera;
    boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
    private Context mContext = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

            if (imageData != null) {

                Intent mIntent = new Intent();

                StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,
                        "ImageName");
                mCamera.startPreview();

                setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                finish();

            }
        }
    };

    protected void onResume() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open();

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");


        // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
        if (mPreviewRunning) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }

        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        mCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Caught exception in surface chagned");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = true;

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mPreviewRunning = false;
        mCamera.release();
    }

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);

    }

    public static boolean StoreByteImage(Context mContext, byte[] imageData,
            int quality, String expName) {

        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File("/sdcard");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        String nameFile;
        try {

            BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 5;

            Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                    imageData.length,options);


            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    sdImageMainDirectory.toString() +"/image.jpg");


            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    fileOutputStream);

            myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, bos);

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is null? pointer to data you received in callback,  content of file on SD card?

Comment: hi,  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) on this line data parameter is null...

Comment: Well, this could have a lot of grounds -   camera configuration is somehow tricky. It would be necessary to see  how do you configure camera, and request callback

Comment: Hi all can you please check now and let me know what could be the problem, I have pasted all the code, Also if you guys think you have some better option please provide me the link so that i can run some new source code to achieve the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I see the problem.  You are reusing picture callback for both raw and jpeg callbacks.  ANd from javadoc you can read:

> Triggers an asynchronous image capture. The camera service will
>   initiate a series of callbacks to the application as the image capture
>   progresses. The shutter callback occurs after the image is captured.
>   This can be used to trigger a sound to let the user know that image
>   has been captured. The raw callback occurs when the raw image data is
>   available (NOTE: the data will be null if there is no raw image
>   callback buffer available or the raw image callback buffer is not
>   large enough to hold the raw image). The postview callback occurs when
>   a scaled, fully processed postview image is available (NOTE: not all
>   hardware supports this). The jpeg callback occurs when the compressed
>   image is available. If the application does not need a particular
>   callback, a null can be passed instead of a callback method.

So if it was called as raw callback,  data could be null. 
If you do not like raw data, just use:

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);
```

Comment: Well , in my case everything works fine on Samsung galaxy note and other high end devices , it even works great on the Emulator , but on devices like HTC Wildfire S and other such low end devices , some

Comment: What if I _do_ want to use raw data?

Comment: What about registering your callback as raw picture callback? ( hint: my javadoc  says that it shall be second parameter )