# Android - NullPointerException onPictureTaken

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception

I have an app that uses a custom camera. I've tried it on a number of devices without an issue, but I recently received a crash report from a Motorola DROID X2 running Android 2.3.5.

LOG:

```
Fatal Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
FileOutputStream.java line 256 java.io.FileOutputStream.write
CameraUtils.java line 29 MY_PACKAGE.camera.CameraUtils.ByteArrayToFile
CameraActivity.java line 297 MY_PACKAGE.camera.CameraActivity$1.onPictureTaken
Camera.java line 542 android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage
```

CameraActivity - OnPictureTaken:

```
private final PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    public final void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        if (checkSDCard()) {

            imageFile = getImageFile();
            Log.i(TAG, imageFile.toString());

            imageFile = CameraUtils.ByteArrayToFile(data, imageFile);

            if (mCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                flipImage(data, imageFile);
            } else { }

            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, Integer.toString(orientation));
                exif.saveAttributes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            performCrop();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, SD_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

};
```

CameraUtils - ByteArrayToFile:

```
26. public final static File ByteArrayToFile(byte[] data, File file) {
27. try {
28.     FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
29.     stream.write(data);
30.     stream.close();
31. } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
32.     Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
33. } catch (IOException e) {
34.     Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
35. }
36. return file;
37. }
```

Since the error is not being caught by FileNotFoundException or IOException, I presume that byte[] data is causing the NullPointerException and not the file itself.

I can't reproduce the issue on any of my personal devices, nor can I find anything online about the device or os, so I was wondering if this is a known issue, if there is a better implementation (such as the solution found here: [NullpointerException onPictureTaken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081348/nullpointerexception-onpicturetaken)), or if I should just set the minimum SDK higher. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is related better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117906/android-picture-call-back-data-is-null

Answer (score 0):

I believe that every pictureTaken should begin with

```
if (data != null)
```

There may be numerous causes for `data` to be **null**, and your code should [be prepared](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSwjuz_-yao).

I don't think it's a defect of ver. 2.3.5, but you could put DROID X2 in blacklist.